# Can we make assumptions on the value of x if cin >> x fails?

Tags: c++, c++11, cin

I had always assumed that if `cin >> x` fails, where `x` is a built-in type such as `int`, then `x` is left at its value prior to the input. However the following code produces different output depending on how `cin` fails:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int x = 10, y = 10;

    cin >> x;
    cin >> y;

    cout << x << " " << y;
}
```

The value of `y` seems to vary depending on the type of failure (^Z representing EOF)

Input `20 ^Z` outputs `20 0`

Input `20 c` output `20 0`

Input `20[ENTER]^Z` outputs `20 10`

Input `20[ENTER] ^Z` outputs `20 0`

So it seems if there is a failure then `int` gets set to the value `0`. However I can't make sense of the third case, where I enter `20`, press enter and then Cntrl+Z, the value of `y` doesn't get changed at all in this circumstance.

How are values set when `cin` fails? Should I make any assumptions about their values? Also, when creating my own input operator for classes, should `cin` failures generally set the class object back to the pre-input value or to a default value instead (`Class()`)?

Comment: A different compiler might behave differently. You can't count on the value when the operation fails.

Comment: @RSahu you can, since C++11

Comment: @M.M, interesting. Good to know.

Comment: @RSahu While the duplicate did help, I still can't really understand the output. `20 ^Z` should be outputting `20 10` if `skipws` is turned on, which it isn't. If I try the input from a file (and swap `cin` to an `ifstream` object) it works as intended.

Comment: Could be a compiler bug, these things are difficult to get right (and library writers say that the spec is a pain)